# Is Websocket enabled in Google app engine Ruby runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5

As in rails 5, action cable can be used as a layer above the application to provide persistent connection (WebSocket). So I created an application and tested locally then deployed it to Google AppEngine flexible environment Ruby runtime. the application runs fine except the WebSocket part.

I checked the console in the browser and found that it keeps giving this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://mydomain.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```